# unity3d error. Decompressing this format (30) is not supported on this platform

Tags: unity-game-engine

I get the following unity3d error when trying to deploy an `AssetBundle` on an Android device:

```
Decompressing this format (30) is not supported on this platform.
```

Comment: Wow! No comments from anybody. Am I in the wrong place? I usually get answers in a few minutes. Maybe I'm in the wrong part of the forum - don't know.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate your question and add more details instead of complaining about the amount of reactions to your post? What is the used `AssetBundle`? What is the Unity version? Could it be realted to the `LZMA` compression as metnioned e.g. here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/decompressing-this-format-1-is-not-supported-on-this-platform.445819 ?